# How do I transfer to a full world in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I want to transfer my characters from my world to a world where my friends are playing, but, their world is full. I tried many times to refresh the the world list and close/open the game but the server I want to transfer is always full.

Is there any other way besides these to transfer to other worlds?

Comment: Your second question, "Are there plans to bring this feature back", is speculation of the future of the industry, and off-topic.  I'd recommend removing that bit.

Comment: I understand it may be speculation, but maybe this information could help me somehow. If you disagree, please, feel free to edit the question.

Comment: It's not that it might not help.  It may, or may not.  It's that we don't allow questions of that type because they are generally unanswerable.  It's hard to prove a negative.  I can edit it for you if you want, but we try not to change the intent of the question; that's up to you, as the asker.  Hence the recommendation that you remove that part.

Comment: +1 .  I'm having this issue as well.  I'm hoping that the fullness of the servers is a temporary thing, but have not seen any anet commentary on the subject.  They'll have to do something soon or (at this rate) no one will be able to join American servers.

Comment: But it't not really speculation [when the developers have always said transfers are only free until guesting has been implemented and the world pops settled, after that it will become paid transfers](https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/a-world-of-choice-the-regions-of-guild-wars-2/)?

Comment: Guesting *so* needs bringing back!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unclear whether the population of a world is based on the number of *players currently online* or the number of *accounts on that world*, but population levels do fluctuate over time. As such, it is possible to transfer onto a full server by trying at a different time of day.

Try checking during off-peak hours, such as early in the morning. I've heard from several guildmates that they've had success transferring onto a normally "Full" world this way.

Comment: While I'm not sure their Community Coordinators have all the relevant information, [CC Eva has commented directly](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/Server-Populations/first#post703192) on what "Full" is supposed to mean?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, and it conflicts with what I've heard from other people... I'll edit my question a bit.

Comment: Interesting, all servers are in "Very High" right now, I could transfer my chars, maybe they gave more slots or something like this. So as you say, maybe it is the ammount of the players logged in and the population fluctuates.

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't - once a server is full, it means you'll need to wait until somebody transfers off that server before you will be able to move to it. While a server is marked as 'full', this means it is locked for transfers to it, or initially associating your account with that server (setting your home server).

Here is an [official source](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/game/gw2/Server-Populations/first#post703192) from 'CC Eva', a community coordinator, explaining how server capacities work:

> when you see a server FULL means that the people who’ve chosen that server as theirs, or players who have moved to that particular server, have reached the cap, independently of where did they create their accounts.

This means that the number of *accounts* with the server as their home server has reached the capacity cap set for that server. Over time if people move away from the server it will become available again for new accounts to choose as their home server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There should be a way where you could exchange a position with other person from both full worlds. But unfortunately all we can do now is wait for a further update in this area.