# Can I refresh the server status without logging out/in?

Tags: guild-wars-2

A friend and I want to join a server that is FULL, so we are waiting for a moment when the server becomes VERY HIGH in population to join.

As far as I know, logging out and in is necessary to refresh the server list.

I can't find on google any server list to refresh on the go to avoid this cumbersome method.

Is there anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking on world selection just randomize the world list, it does not refresh or update it. As far as I know, logging in and out would be the only option to refresh the world list. Also, you may want to check [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95813/how-do-i-transfer-to-a-full-world-in-guild-wars-2) I made.